# Re-navigate to a particular view in multi-view region

Tags: wpf, prism, region, regionadapter

I'm working on a WPF application that's utilizing the Microsoft Prism framework.  One aspect of the application is a "modal" region that can hold any number of modal windows that overlays over the entire window.  As more views are navigated into the region, each window slides to the right to allow the new window to occupy the center of the screen.  Here's a more visual explanation:

When the "modal" region contains a single view:

[image: When the "modal" region contains a single view]

When another view is added to the region:

[image: When another view is added to the region]

When several more views are added:

[image: When several more views are added]

I have this working using a custom control that manages the animation and display of its children.  Here's what the control's custom `RegionAdapter`'s `Adapt` method looks like:

```
protected override void Adapt(IRegion region, ModalContainer regionTarget)
{
    region.ActiveViews.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler((o, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach(FrameworkElement element in e.NewItems)
            {
                regionTarget.AddChild(element);
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach (FrameworkElement element in e.OldItems)
            {
                regionTarget.RemoveChild(element);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My question is this:  **What's the best way to navigate back to an earlier window?**  Right now, the only way I know to trigger the `RemoveChild` method above is to explicitly remove the view from the region, which requires that I keep a list of all the views currently in the region somewhere:

```
// to remove the most recently added view from the region
_regionManager.Regions["ModalRegion"].Remove(addedViews.Pop());
```

Ideally, I would be able to navigate backwards using Prism's "journaling" concept, but I don't see a way in my `RegionAdapter` to respond to when a view already in the region is re-navigated to.

Any hints would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I was able to achieve this functionality by following a suggestion by GOstrowsky (see the comments in the accepted answer) - I changed my region adapter to only maintain a single active view in the region (the view currently in the center of the screen).  I then can target that view for removal via `myRegion.ActiveViews.FirstOrDefault()`.

**YET ANOTHER EDIT**

I have since changed this implementation yet again, as we needed the ability to remove *any* of the views currently in the region, not just the last one.  See the accepted answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, I solved this problem by only allowing a single region to be active, which guaranteed that removing the region's currently active view always removed the view currently in the center of the screen.  However, since then, we've needed the ability to remove *any* of the views from the region, not just the first.  To accomplish this, I realized that the `Region.Views` property can be cast to a `List` and then accessed by index:

```
List<object> allViews = modalRegion.Views.ToList<object>();
```

I'm a little uncomfortable with this solution, since the `IViewsCollection` definition inherits from `IEnumerable`, not `IList`; technically I could be handed a custom `IViewsCollection` that cannot be cast to an `IList`.... but in the short term I'm going to run with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you would ocassionally want to Navigate back to a previous *View*, you should not remove it from the *Region* when Navigating from it.

Instead, you could just deactivate it from the ***OnNavigatedFrom()*** method. And then, use the ***NavigationJournal*** to navigate back.

Regarding your *RegionAdapter* control you could modify it so that it could handle *View* activation and de-activation. For example, you could ***Publish*** a ***De/ActivationChanged*** event from each *ViewModel* ***OnNavigatedFrom()*** and ***OnNavigatedTo()***, and handle these events on your custom control by Subscribing to it and performing the corresponding task to each event.

You can find more information about Navigation and **Event Aggregation** in the following **MSDN Prism Guide** chapters:

- [8: Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)
- [Event Aggregation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec8)

I hope this helps,
Regards.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  When I say I want to "navigate back to an earlier view", I mean a view that still exists in region - one of the views sitting off to the right-hand side of the screen.  Once a modal window is dismissed (animated off the screen to the left), I won't ever need to re-navigate to that same instance of the view.

Comment: Instead of keeping a list of Views in the Region, you could make the centered View to be the only Active one in the Region. And the Views on the left could have the **IsActive** property set to false. Therefore, the Views on the left would still be displayed and when removing the centered View, you could get it with: "***Region.ActiveViews.firstOrDefault()***". The following Navigated View would get its IsActive property to true at the ***OnNavigatedTo()*** method.

Comment: I ended up tracking which view was to be removed by only maintaining a single active view in the region, as you suggested.  Thanks for the help!